# form is not working, I used HTML5 & bootstrap 3.0?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

form is not working, I used HTML5 & bootstrap 3.0?

here i add the link of the site please checkout.
I cant figure-out it.

http://www.deliveryguys.in/html/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's usually best to post snippits of code that you think are malfunctioning but in this case I think you should invest in a spellchecker.

I went to

http://www.deliveryguys.in/html/index.html

And it seems to work fine.

Notice it's HTML instead of HMTL

Edit: OK now I see the real problem with your code

The form is underneath other HTML elements. You need to give your stylings z-indexes in order to control what is on top of what. I gave the form a z-index of 1000 and it worked fine. I suggest editing your css classes to include z-indexes to give you finer control than that.

Comment: And it is bootstrap instead of bootstarp ...

Answer (score 0):

Please note that your form action has been mapped to "#"

Kindly point the form action to the appropriate server page & it will start working.

Regards

SRIRAM NATARAJAN
(Chennai, Tamil Nadu, India)
(www.thesriram.co.in)